# Jekyll: How to use for loop to generate table row within the same table inside markdown

Tags: for-loop, markdown, jekyll

I am trying to generate a table, based on the posts that I have. Now, the challenge here is that this is inside a markdown file, so for each row that I generate, liquid seems to generate a new table for each generated row. Is there a way to fit all rows inside one single table?

Here is my code:

```
|Title  |Link  |
|---|---|
{% for my_post in site.posts %}
  {% if my_post.title %}
|{{ my_post.title }}  |[Click Here]({{ my_post.url }})  |
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The generated output looks like this
[image]

As you can see, the outcome is actually a messed-up table header row + two separate tables. Can I really generate rows and fit them all inside one table? or am I better off switching to html code?

Comment: Can you explain plz where the site obj is from. How to include it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The liquid markup introduces line breaks in markdown.

**Edit :** you can now manage use [whitespace control in Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/)

> In Liquid, you can include a hyphen in your tag syntax `{{-`, `-}}`, `{%-`, and `-%}` to strip whitespace from the left or right side of a rendered tag.

```
|Title  |Link  |
|---|---|
{% for my_post in site.posts -%}
{% if my_post.title -%}
|{{ my_post.title }}  |[Click Here]({{ my_post.url }})  |
{% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

**old answer**

If you put your liquid tags on same line you'll have a valid table outputed.

```
| Title | Link |
|---|---|{% for my_post in site.posts %}{% if my_post.title %}
|{{ my_post.title }}  |[Click Here]({{ my_post.url }})  |{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am late in the game (as in fiddling with Markdown), so your explanation is much appreciated.